# Are there any good examples of a state machine implemented in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm looking to reference a good example of a state machine implemented in Julia. Do any exist?

I'm aware of https://github.com/tensorjack/FiniteStateMachine.jl, but I'm not looking for a library that facilitates state machine implementations (especially with the overhead that this specific implementation likely entails).

Specifically, I'm wondering if there's a great example of how this is done clearly and concisely without an explict enum type to represent states.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less-than-ideal implementation of a state machine for parsing CSV files (and why I asked the question originally): https://github.com/benhamner/XSV.jl/blob/master/src/readxsv.jl#L28

When I get the chance to try to improve it (refactoring for simplicity + speed optimization), I'll update this answer with what I learn.